# Adding a menu item onto the right click of Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, vsix

I am creating a visual studio extension to cut down some mundane code for myself I am trying to add an extension menu onto the right click of the project explorer it should then launch a form once actioned

```
private CreateCrud(Package package)
{
        if (package == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
        }

        this.package = package;

        OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
        if (commandService != null)
        {
            var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
            var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
            commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
        }
}
```

In My Class I am calling the Initialize event ok.

```
  protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress) {
        // When initialized asynchronously, the current thread may be a background thread at this point.
        // Do any initialization that requires the UI thread after switching to the UI thread.

        CreateCrud.Initialize(this);
        await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress);
        Dte = await GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
        Instance = this;
        Logger.Initialize(this, "Ef Core CRUD Generator");
        await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But For some reason its not placing it on the menu.

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the singleton instance of the command.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="package">Owner package, not null.</param>
public static void Initialize(Package package)
{
    Instance = new CreateCrud(package);
}
```

I copied the code from another open source extension which Included this guid. Do I need to generate a guid specific for my program is that why its not showing.

```
public const string PackageGuidString = "9615efc3-3943-4297-9fdf-0ca3680b1d1f";
```

This is the code that should launch the form

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Create the window with the unused ID.
   using (DpiAwareness.EnterDpiScope(DpiAwarenessContext.SystemAware))
   {
      var obj = new frmExtension();
       obj.Show();
   }    


}
```

When I am debugging I am going to my instance of visual studio:

> Start External Program with : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>
> Command Line Arguments:  /rootsuffix Exp

But its not attached itself to the menu

Comment: Always generate your own GUID. The whole point of a GUID is that it's globally unique! :-)

Comment: Would need to see the .vsct to check the command placement.